# Convert a message into a list

Tags: python, discord.py

I wanted to do a roll command on my discordbot and i wanted to convert the message into a list and wait `x` seconds before revealing the roll.

But when I split the message and print it, it returns `<built-in method split of str object at 0x0000021B3AA202B0>`.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('wroll'):
        await message.channel.send(message.content.split)
        start= int(message.content.split()[1])
        end = int(message.content.split()[2])
        txt = []
        txt.append(message.content.split)
        await message.channel.send(txt)
        
        if len(txt) == 4:
            print(True)
            waiting = int(txt[3])
            
            for i in range(waiting+1,0,-1):
                await message.channel.send(i)
                sleep(1)
        await message.channel.send(randint(start,end))

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: `split` is a method, you need to call it.

Answer (score 0):

Typo, missing brackets on `txt.append(message.content.split)`, should be `txt.append(message.content.split())`